# CMake - Could not find a package configuration file provided by "QT"

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I've got some problems with CMake. It shows me an error when I try to configure my build for Visual Studio 2019. Everything looks fine to me when I check the CMakeLists.txt, but something is still wrong. The file was auto created by Qt, I just added some things to connect some directories. What can I do to solve this problem?

Here is the error:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29334.0
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: D:/VS/VS-IDE/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "QT" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt6Config.cmake
    qt6-config.cmake
    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "QT" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "QT_DIR" to
  a directory containing one of the above files.  If "QT" provides a separate
  development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(bacteria LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package(Qt5 ...) call.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets LinguistTools REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets LinguistTools REQUIRED)

#Mine add
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

set(TS_FILES bacteria_ru_RU.ts)

#Mine add
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64")

if(ANDROID)
  add_library(bacteria SHARED
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
    #My add
    mainmatrix.cpp
    mainmatrix.h
    microbe.cpp
    microbe.h
    microbecontainer.cpp
    microbecontainer.h
    food.cpp
    food.h
    ${TS_FILES}
  )
else()
  add_executable(bacteria
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
    #My add
    mainmatrix.cpp
    mainmatrix.h
    microbe.cpp
    microbe.h
    microbecontainer.cpp
    microbecontainer.h
    food.cpp
    food.h
    ${TS_FILES}
  )
endif()

target_link_libraries(bacteria PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
```

Comment: Do you have those files? When CMake does this if you do what the error message says and tell cmakegui where the folder is by setting the `QT_DIR` it will find it.

Comment: Why is the prefix path `D:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64` if you are using msvc instead of mingw `The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29334.0`? That is clearly wrong. Mingw binaries are not compatible with msvc.

Comment: The command `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64")` need to be changed to `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64")`  (you may need to download and install the appropriate Qt version for your platform) and placed **before** the `find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)` command. Remove all other unused `find_package(QT ...` and `find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} ...` commands.

Comment: The last reply worked for me. Thanks for the answers. Now I have another problem. I don't know why, but the program runs slower in VS than in Qt. Why is that so ?

Comment: Can you provide some timings? Are we talking of 10s vs. 12s or rather 10s vs. 100s or worse? Without timings it's quite hard to guess.

Comment: ***I don't know why, but the program runs slower in VS than in Qt. Why is that so*** Make sure that you time only Release mode in Visual Studio. I have seen cases were Debug mode took 100 times longer to execute ( because of the additional debug mode checking that goes on).

Answer (score 10):

adding **set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/Users/YOURPATH/Qt/6.1.0/clang_64")**
this line of code before the **find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)** solved the problem for me (macOS).Find the QT directory and copy the path of the /clang_64 file. If you have problems with QT then try to reinstall https://www.qt.io/download-open-source?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5

Comment: That's not going to work on other people's computers though.

Comment: For anyone reading this, a proper way to do this would be to run `cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/compiler`. This also solves the problem from @Oscar

Answer (score 7):

In case if you are experiencing the same problem on Mac, here's what I added before
`find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)`:

`set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Qt/6.1.2/macos/lib/cmake")`

In my case cmake contained a lot of folders, many of which had `.cmake` files. Apparently CMake found the required packages there.

Comment: I found that this was happening in a new project on Mac because I'd left the default "Generic Darwin" kit selected when generating the app. There appears to be no Qt5config.cmake file for that configuration; you have to use the "Desktop Qt..." one. I don't know how you retroactively change that choice in a project.

Comment: This worked for me for Qt 6.4.0 on macos

Comment: That's going to break the project for other people or other computers not set up exactly the same way.

Comment: @Oscar your statement is applicable to nearly any situation in programming. I tried to give the most general answer I could :)